# Search and print record in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I am using grep to search a text based database that holds contact info. However, it prints the : delimiter from the text file. How do I remove the delimiter or change it to a tab?

```
DATAFILE
Name:Address:Phone:Email
Stan Marsh:123 South Park:456:sm@cc.com
```

Each line has its own record. I tried using grep, awk, cut, tr, but I can't get it to output without the darn : I saw a lot of tutorials on printing a databases first column or even several but I just need print without delimiters(or replace them) after searching for it. I saw how to print a whole file with no delimiters or even replacing them but I'm having a hard time combining that with a grep search:/

Comment: Have you tried piping the result of grep to sed so you can replace ':' with anything you want ?

Comment: `awk -F:  -v OFS="\t" '{print $3,$4 }' file` prints just phone and emai separated by tab char. Change `$3,$4` to get the fields you want OR use $0 to print the whole line. Does that help? Please take an hour or two and work thru the `awk` tutorial at www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html . Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

### use `sed` to replace it:

```
cat yourFileName|grep YourKeyWord | sed -e 's/:/\t/g'
```

Comment: \t means the tab delimiter